# Como faço para abrir um link enviado por e-mail ao logar?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou enviando um link para um usuário, só que como ele não está logado ele direciona para a pagina de login, só que quando ele coloca usuário e senha ele vai para a pagina principal do sistema php, como eu faço para que ao digitar o usuário e senha ele abre o link e não seja redirecionado para pagina principal?

Abaixo o código que valida o login

```
 <?php
$session_start();
$usuariot = $_POST['usuario'];
$senhat = $_POST['senha'];
include_once("conexao.php");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM proj_usuarios WHERE user_nome='$usuariot' AND user_senha='$senhat' LIMIT 1");
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if(empty($resultado)){
echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='../login_giga.php';</script>";
die();
}else{
$_SESSION['usuarioID'] = $resultado['user_id'];
$_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['user_nome'];
$_SESSION['usuarioSenha'] = $resultado['user_senha'];
$_SESSION['usuarioNivel'] = $resultado['user_nivel'];
$_SESSION['usuarionick'] = $resultado['nickname'];

if($_SESSION['usuarioNivel'] == 1){ 
header("Location:../paginas/layout/dashboard.php");
}}
?>
```

Obrigado

Comment: Você precisa armazenar, de alguma forma, a origem do usuário quando fizer o redirecionamento para a página de login. Muitas aplicações utilizam a própria query string da URL: `Location: /login/?from=/pagina/foo`. Na validação dos dados, se sucesso, redireciona de volta: `Location $_GET["from"]`, ou algo do gênero. É disso que precisa?

Comment: Pelo que entendi seria isso, fazer o login e redirecionar de volta para o link que foi enviado. Hoje envio link e a pessoa, depois de logar,cola novamente o link